# How do I print punctuation right after a variable? Python

Tags: python, string, printing, punctuation

```
s = "A Colon is beside me"
print s,":"
```

I should get

> > > A Colon is beside me :

But I wanna get

```
>>>A Colon is beside me:
```

How?

Comment: isn't that just your interrupter?

Answer (score 8):

Concatenate the strings:

```
print s + ':'
```

or use string formatting:

```
print '{0}:'.format(s)
```

On python 3, the `print()` function can also be told to use an empty separator between multiple arguments, instead of a space:

```
print(s, ':', sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

This definatly works. (I am new to the site and I have put normal text not code!?)

```
 print "%s:" % s
```

The %s means insert a variable here and the second s means insert the specific variable 's

Answer (score 0):

This is for summarization purpose.

There are four ways to print statement:

s = "A Colon is beside me"

Data Type Parsing Mode:

`print("%s:" %s)`

Variables Concatenation Mode:

`print(s+":")`

format() method:

`print("{}:".format(s))`

Using Built-in function:

`print(s,':',sep='')`